# custom headers in CURL apache module not being recognized

Tags: c, apache, loops, redirect, curl

This is code I have so far. Please ignore the unused variables as I only am displaying the important code fragments:

```
typedef struct{
    char* rheaders[500][500]; //HTML headers
    char* curltemp[50000];    //Temp string space for CURL function
    char* alias[5000];
    char* idx[5000];
    char* redirurl[5000];
    unsigned long rhdrct;
    unsigned long idxct;
    unsigned long aliasct;
    unsigned long notrail;
    unsigned long nologall;
    unsigned long httpstatus;
    unsigned long print;
}Iconfig;
static Iconfig conf;
static CURL *curl;

static size_t curlH(char *buffer,size_t size,size_t nitems,void *userdata){
    //store data as it comes in. This works
    snprintf((char*)conf.rheaders[conf.rhdrct++],(size*nitems)-1,"%s\0",(char*)buffer);
    return (size*nitems);
}

static int getnewURL(request_rec *r){
    curl=curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){
        struct curl_slist *chunk=NULL;char cc[1000];
        //This header below isn't being sent with request
        chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "x-custom: 1;"); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
        //Request from server this code is executed on
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/test");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA,conf.curltemp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,curlH);
        CURLcode res=curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        //iterate and display all headers after request is done
        ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_CRIT, 0, r->server, "Headers...");
        unsigned long i;
        for (i=0;i<conf.rhdrct;i++){
            ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_CRIT, 0, r->server, "%d %s",i,conf.rheaders[i]);
        }
    }
}

static int handler(request_rec *r){
    // This happens on every request including those from CURL
    if (!ap_is_initial_req(r)){return DECLINED;}
    //check headers to see if x-custom is set to 1
    const char*a=apr_table_get(r->headers_in,"x-custom"); 
    if (a){
        if (strcmp("1",a)==0){
            //pass on new x-received header sent via CURL and process normally
            //but this stage never happens
            char b[1000];sprintf(b,"%s recvd\0",a);
            apr_table_set(r->headers_out,"x-received:",b);
            ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_CRIT, 0, r->server, "Subrequest");
            return DECLINED;
        }
    }
    //execute request in CURL and stop this apache process
    getnewURL(r);
    return DONE;
}
```

I managed to retrieve standard headers from different URLs via my code, but what I want to do is insert a header, pass it to my code again via my server URL domain (127.0.0.1) and use that header to determine if curl has been executed at least once. If I don't do this properly, then an increasingly number of handler functions will be executed causing an apache server lockup.

My end goal is to create an internal redirect system so that when a guest requests a URL from the server that results in a http 301 status redirect to a url that results in another http 301 status redirect etc, the server instead will consolidate those redirects so that the user will only have to put up with only one redirect.

My problem lies at the `//but this stage never happens` line.

Does anyone know how I can fix this, or does anyone have a better method to make the apache module (handler function) recognize that the incoming URL request comes from my getnewURL function?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out. I had these settings in my apache configuration file:

```
MinSpareServers 1
MaxSpareServers 1
MaxClients 1
StartServers 1
```

I then changed the numbers from 1 to 5 and now things work.